# Is main method also allocated in heap?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, program-entry-point

I read that "Every object in Java allocated in heap."

I also came to know that "Every program, object is inherited by Object class" I am not sure of the class name though.

So if our program that includes main method is also inherited by object class in Java Virtual Machine, does it mean that it is also an object? Is main method also allocated in heap? If it is then does it mean everything in Java is allocated in heap?

Comment: Are you asking about the actual `main` method itself, or the variables inside it?

Comment: @chrylis About `main`  method I guess. Not method variables.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I was asking to clarify, since it appears the OP may not be conversant enough with the terminology to know that they're distinct.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, I'm also looking for the response of OP. That is what I wildly guessed/understood :) Still unclear though.

Comment: Yes, Every method in java stored in special heap space called "Method Area" you can get more about it [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html)

Comment: @chrylis I was asking both of them. main method itself and the variables inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM spec on [run-time data areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5) may be helpful. When you launch your program, the class with the `main` method is loaded by the JVM's bootstrap class loader. A Java class loader adds the methods of each class loaded into the JVM's **method area**, which is a shared memory pool where all the executable code for Java classes goes. It then allocates a **frame** to hold the variables defined inside the `main` method; whether this frame is allocated on the stack or on the heap is implementation-dependent.

Comment: As I understand with your answer is:
Every definitions of classes is stored in method area. Then when a class is initialized, an object created it is just simply connect itself with links to method area. Object is actually in heap but because all methods are shared they are in method area.
Did I understand right?

Comment: @mtilhan When you're talking about runtime, the abstraction of "the object" is no longer helpful. An instance of a class (the usual meaning of "an object") consists of a type (the class) and instance variables. The class has methods and perhaps static variables that belong to it. The JVM keeps a data structure for each instance's variables that includes information on which class it is, and it knows where to look up those methods from the method area. This data structure logically lives on the heap.

Comment: @mtilhan Keep in mind that all these descriptions are abstract specifications of the JVM's behavior, and the JVM implementation may do things in other ways as long as they look identical. In particular, if the JVM can determine that no reference to a class leaves a particular method call, the JVM may put that class's instance variables on the physical stack instead of the physical heap (this is called *escape analysis*). The stack of the host computer and the stack of the JVM are distinct.

Answer (score 2):

The class definition itself (including methods such as main) is allocated in a special area of the JVM. Classloaders are responsible for putting it there.

When a class is loaded you can make references to it. Local references (such as those defined in a method) are allocated on the stack as part of the stack frame for the method. The actual object that the reference points to is allocated on the heap. Objects that have reference fields are allocated on the heap along with the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

in Java, notion of class is somewhat misleading. On one hand, it is a minimal program and a component of complex programs. On the other hand, it is a reference data type. When it is claimed "all classes are inherited from Object", class is meant as data type. But only non-static members of a class define the data type. Static members like `static void main()` are parts of a program but not parts of data type. So `main` has no relation with `Object` and heap.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are not objects, and so are not stored on the heap. There is, however, an auxiliary storage area in the JVM where constant permanent data are stored. Those are data that need not get garbage collected, like data in a class file. (Some JVMs may perform class garbage collection, though.)

So, coming back to your question, when we have this:

```
class X {
   public static void main(String[] args) { .... }
}
```

when `main` is called, there is not an instance of X yet. Nor does Java require us to create an instance of X. In fact, many beginner programs just have a bunch of static methods, and so the class degenerates to just a namespace.

So, apart from a few objects the Java runtime itself creates (like, for example, the `args` array and the elements in it), there is nothing in the heap upon start of `main`.